# Is it possible to dump the core but not exit the process?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, coredump

I want to be able to generate a core dump but not exit the process afterwards. I don't need it to continue execution, just not die. This is a C++ Ubuntu process.

I believe I'm dumping the core in a pretty standard way: I catch the offending signal via setting the signal handler with signal(), I set the core size limit via setrlimit() and then I prompt the core dump with signal() and raise():

```
signal(SIGSEGV, OnPosixSignal);

...

void OnPosixSignal(int iSignal)
{
    struct rlimit CoreLimit;
    CoreLimit.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
    CoreLimit.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &CoreLimit);
    signal(iSignal, SIG_DFL);
    raise(iSignal);
}
```

Is there something I can do to not have the process exit after dumping the core?

Comment: Have you taken a look at how `gcore` does this?

Comment: I've not found `setrlimit()` on the list of async-safe functions. Are you sure it's a good idea to call it in a signal-handler?

Comment: `coredumper` library will be your friend.

Comment: First, just call `setrlimit()` when your process starts instead of in the SIGSEGV handler - that way you don't need a signal handler.  Second, how do you propose to continue from something like a SIGSEGV?  If you try to ignore it, the condition that caused the signal to be raised will still exist.

Comment: Side note: you should use `sigaction(2)` to catch the signal. `signal(2)` hinders portability because its behavior varies across UNIX versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do that using [`gcore`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html):

> Generate a core dump of a running program with process ID pid. Produced file is equivalent to a kernel produced core file as if the process crashed (and if "ulimit -c" were used to set up an appropriate core dump limit).  Unlike after a crash, after gcore the program remains running without any change.